# What are other ways to get this result set

Tags: sql-server

What are other ways to get the same result set

I am using 4 tables

```
SELECT * FROM Terminal
SELECT * FROM Customer
SELECT * FROM Contract
SELECT * FROM ExternalTable
```

Data in these 4 tables are as below:

[image]

The query that i've written is

```
    select ex.TerminalName,ex.CustomerName from ExternalTable ex
except
select t.TerminalName,ct.CustomerName from [Contract] c
inner join Terminal t on t.TerminalID=c.TerminalID
inner join Customer ct on ct.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
```

Which gets the below result

[image]

So just curious to know what are the other ways to get this same result

Comment: You should edit the question and describe what you want the query to do.  A query that works for really small tables might not capture the essence of what you intend.

Comment: This question lacks a problem to solve. You need a clear objective so that there can be a single clear answer that fully meets this objective. What you have right now encourages multiple correct answers, with no way to know which one is right. In a sense this is more social than professional, and so as asked it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really what you are looking for, but here is another way to write the query that should produce the same results:

```
SELECT 
    ex.TerminalName,
    ex.CustomerName 
FROM 
    ExternalTable ex
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT
                    NULL
                FROM        
                    [Contract] c
                INNER JOIN 
                    Terminal t on t.TerminalID = c.TerminalID
                INNER JOIN 
                    Customer ct on ct.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                WHERE
                    t.TerminalName = ex.TerminalName
                AND
                    ex.CustomerName = ct.CustomerName
                )
```

Comment: This is want exactly what i want, but any more ways to do this?

Comment: how to do select * from externaltable with except

Comment: the except clause requires both queries to have the same number of columns / types, so if you have to do * with external table you would have to make your second select from your code return all the columns that match the table layout of externaltable, although I would generally stay away from select *.

Comment: How to do this without subquery using join to get same result

Answer (score 1):

This ought to be equivalent:

```
select ex.TerminalName,ex.CustomerName
from
    ExternalTable ex
    left outer join
    (
        [Contract] c
        inner join Terminal t
            on t.TerminalID=c.TerminalID
        inner join Customer ct
            on ct.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
    )
        on ex.TerminalName = t.TerminalName and ex.CustomerName = ct.CustomerName
where t.TerminalName is null and ct.CustomerName is null
```

You should note that `except` returns distinct results and to be strictly equivalent I would need to specify `select distinct`.

Comment: What do you mean by "'works' well" and "more ways"? If you mean a query "'performs' well", you should compare execution plans and consider their costs. If you believe different "ways" **must** produce **different** execution plans, you might be surprised to discover execution plans are identical... When comparing execution plans, be sure you are presenting SQL Server with realistic row counts and realistic distributions of values. Those comparisons and conditions are needed, because SQL is an _interpreted_ (**not** a procedural) language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a self-contained example that shows two alternatives.
One uses NOT IN, and the other uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but they should be equivalent.

```
--set up temp tables with dummy data to replicate the issue

declare @Terminal table(terminalid int,terminalname nvarchar(100));
insert into @Terminal select 1,'Terminal1' union select 2,'Terminal2'

declare @Customer table(customerid int,customername nvarchar(100));
insert into @Customer select 1,'Customer1' union select 2,'Customer2';

declare @Contract table(contractid int,terminalid int,customerid int,contractname nvarchar(100));
insert into @Contract select 1,1,1,'Contract1';

declare @ExternalTable table(externalid int,terminalname nvarchar(100),customername nvarchar(100),contractname nvarchar(100));
insert into @ExternalTable select 1,'Terminal1','Customer1','Contract1' union select 2,'Terminal2','Customer1','Contract1'

--SELECT * FROM @Terminal
--SELECT * FROM @Customer
--SELECT * FROM @Contract
--SELECT * FROM @ExternalTable

--goal: show records that are in the external table, but are not fully linked in the other tables

--original
select ex.TerminalName,ex.CustomerName from @ExternalTable ex
except
select t.TerminalName,ct.CustomerName from @Contract c
inner join @Terminal t on t.TerminalID=c.TerminalID
inner join @Customer ct on ct.CustomerId=c.CustomerId

--revised (left outer join method)
select et.TerminalName,et.CustomerName
from
  @ExternalTable et
  left join (
    select ex.externalid
    from
      @Contract c
      inner join @Terminal t on t.TerminalID=c.TerminalID
      inner join @Customer ct on ct.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
      inner join @ExternalTable ex on ex.terminalname = t.terminalname and ex.customername = ct.customername
  ) excludes on excludes.externalid = et.externalid
where excludes.externalid is null

--revised ("not in" method)
select et.TerminalName,et.CustomerName
from
  @ExternalTable et
where et.externalid not in(
  select ex.externalid
  from
    @Contract c
    inner join @Terminal t on t.TerminalID=c.TerminalID
    inner join @Customer ct on ct.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
    inner join @ExternalTable ex on ex.terminalname = t.terminalname and ex.customername = ct.customername
  )
```